# Visual Studio Code doesn't stage Git merge changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Using Git as a source control provider in Visual Studio Code I have an issue whenever I try to merge a conflict file with remote repository keeping my current version.

The steps are the following:

- A file has been modified on remote repository and I modify the same file on the 
  local repository
- When I try to push my changes to the server I recieve (correctly) an error 
  message (no-fast-forward) and I must perform a pull to update my local 
  repository
- When pulling, the editor warn me about the conflict on the file, giving me four 
  option (Accept Current Change, Accept Incoming Change, Accept Both Changes, 
  Compare Changes)
- I accept the current change (my local version) and save the file. When I try to 
  stage the change the file is not added to the section STAGED CHANGES but it 
  disappears. Git remain in a "merging" status and I can't do anything (a push 
  gives me the same error of the first push and a pull gives me an error like I 
  didn't resolved the conflict; in fact in the .git folder I still have the 
  MERGE_HEAD file)

If I Accept the Incoming Change, Accept Both Changes or add additional chars to my previous version (to change the version I tried to commit before) everything works fine. I think that when I choose "Accept Current Change" and try to stage merge changes the editor (or Git?) doesn't add the file to the STAGED CHANGES because it's identical to the version previously committed, and doesn't update the git status, that remains stuck in merge conflict.

The workaround of adding additional chars to the previous version when merging works fine, but I need to know if it's a bug or I'm missing some steps when merging.

Please don't reply me with command line workaround (like git merge --abort), I'm looking for a UI friendly solution (not all of my team mates are confident with command line). Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your not prepared to use the command line (which is the best way to use GIT) then I'd recommend you use [GIT extensions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) not VS code. The VS Code git interface is clunky at best and hides important features of how GIT works

Comment: Hi Liam, I need to use VS Code because it's integrated (with another extension) with my server side platform, Salesforce in this case.

Comment: You can use VSCode. What I mean is don't use GIT though VS Code. TBH if you want to use GIT successfully you really need to understand GIT (and I mean everyone in your team). I'd suggest that anyone "not...confident with command line" is going to struggle. If you find typing `git pull` in a command line difficult how are you going to understand the difference between a `merge` and a `rebase`? A UI isn't much use if you don't know what's going on under the hood. Read though the [GIT docs as a minimum](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).

Comment: I red the GIT documentaiton, I know what's under the hood, my question is about GIT integration with Visual Studio Code. I know that using GIT only with command line would avoid me many problems and would give me full control of GIT flow. It's easy to say "don't use GIT with VS Code", but this is not my question. I specified that I want to know if there's a VS Code bug or if I missing something during the merging operations.

Comment: Yes this really is a bug report, Matteo, the UI should recognize the merge needs to be completed with a commit rather than stating there are no changes to commit. It looks like there's one open for it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7989

Answer (score 1):

This was [a bug in Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7989) which has been fixed in [commit 578d7381da3e9d559e9326375b67429a5de3027d](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/578d7381da3e9d559e9326375b67429a5de3027d) and was shipped in November 2020 with version 1.52.0 of VS Code.